# IF else statement throws an error in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am novice in R. I am trying to assign some values to column based on if else statement. But it keeps throwing me error. Could some help me understand what the error is for?

Code:

```
if (REAR[mean < (-2) & mean > 2,]) {
  REAR$EXCEPTION_1<-1; REAR$EXCEPTION_2<-0
} else  if(REAR[!(mean < (-2) & mean > 2) & deviation > 1.5,])  {
  REAR$EXCEPTION_1<-0; REAR$EXCEPTION_2<-1
} else {
  REAR$EXCEPTION_1<-0; REAR$EXCEPTION_2<-0
}


Error:
Error:
Error in mean < (-5) : 
  comparison (3) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Sample data:

```
dput(head(REAR))

structure(list(TIMESTAMP = structure(list(c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), c(45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 0L), c(17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 19L), c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L
), c(114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L), c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), c(216L, 216L, 216L, 216L, 216L, 216L), c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), c("IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST"), c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
)), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), ID = c(28808, 28808, 
28808, 28808, 28808, 28808), CONNECTION= c("UP", "UP", 
"UP", "UP", "UP", "UP"), ACTIVE = c(68.814, 68.814, 
68.814, 68.814, 68.814, 68.814), SET = c(70, 
70, 70, 70, 70, 70), MODE = c("Cool", "Cool", "Cool", 
"Cool", "Cool", "Cool"), STATUS = c("Occupied", "Occupied", 
"Occupied", "Occupied", "Occupied", "Occupied"), KNOB= c("On", 
"On", "On", "On", "On", "On"), loopN = c(140805L, 140805L, 140805L, 
140805L, 140805L, 140805L), timediff = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15), diff= c(-1.18600000000001, -1.18600000000001, 
-1.18600000000001, -1.18600000000001, -1.18600000000001, -1.18600000000001
), mean = c(-1.67920000000001, -1.67920000000001, -1.67920000000001, 
-1.67920000000001, -1.67920000000001, -1.67920000000001), deviation= c(0.553944943112579, 
0.553944943112579, 0.553944943112579, 0.553944943112579, 0.553944943112579, 
0.553944943112579), EXCEPTION_1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), EXCEPTION_2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("TIMESTAMP", 
"ID", "CONNECTION", "ACTIVE ", "SET", 
"MODE", "STATUS", "KNOB", 
"loopN", "timediff", "diff", "mean", "deviation", 
"EXCEPTION_1", "EXCEPTION_2"), row.names = 764:769, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The `dput` output also gives a warning message `Warning message:
In is.na(secs) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'`

Comment: You have to access the column "mean" in a different way, e.g with `REAR$mean`

Comment: @Kaushal Consider using `ifelse`

Comment: Your `dput` doesn't show a data.table. Please clarify why you've tagged the question "data.table". If you don't deal with a data.table you probably intend `REAR[REAR$mean < (-2) & REAR$mean > 2,]`. However, that would still give a data.frame as the result whereas `if` needs one logical value ( and `ifelse` would need a vector of logical values). You should describe what you want to achieve because your code doesn't look like we do such things in R.

Comment: It is not clear whether you have two datasets or one. For example. `REAR$EXCEPTION_1<-0; SAT$EXCEPTION_2<-0`

Comment: @akrun..they are not two datasets...its single data set and i want to update the column values if they falls in the condition..

Comment: @Kaushal I was referring to `REAR` and `SAT`.

Comment: @akrun..editing error sorry...updated now

Answer (score 2):

Your error is coming from the incapability of the "[" function to "know" that you intend to use 'mean' as a column name. The only `mean` it is able to find is the function mean and trying to compare to a numeric throws the particular error you got.  (It's generally bad practice to name columns with tokens that are also names for common functions, but that's not the cause of the error. If there had been a variable named `mean` the interpreter would have used its value. Column names are not "visible" to operators unless you expose them using `with` or using `[[name]]` or other tricky devices like `eval` or `substitute` that allow specification of an "evaluation environment")

Alternate (but probably not a a successful one):

```
if ( with(REAR , mean < (-2) & mean > 2) ) {
  REAR$EXCEPTION_1<-1; REAR$EXCEPTION_2<-0
   } else { if( with( REAR, !( mean < (-2) & mean > 2) & 
                                standardeviation > 1.5)
              )  { REAR$EXCEPTION_1<-0; REAR$EXCEPTION_2<-1
              } else {  REAR$EXCEPTION_1<-0; SAT$EXCEPTION_2<-0
                                           }
            }
```

But has been pointed out this doesn't solve the further difficulty of assuming that R is SAS (or SPSS). In R there is no implicit looping along column vectors when using the `if(.){.}else{.}`-construct. `ifelse` can be used to choose between two (possibly computed) vector of values on the basis of a logical antecedent vector. In any case you need to learn R's vectorization methods The first condition could be handled by coercing a logical vector converted to a Boolean 0/1 numeric value by multiplying by 1:

```
REAR$EXCEPTION_1 <- with(REAR , mean < (-2) & mean > 2)*1 # *1 makes numeric
```

WAIT A MINUTE! It's not possible to ever satisfy that condition. Are you confused about the meaning of AND and OR in constructing logical expressions? Shouldn't it be ???? :

```
REAR$EXCEPTION_1 <- with(REAR , mean < (-2) | mean > 2)*1
```

And the second consequence can be:

```
REAR$EXCEPTION_2 <- with(REAR, !(mean < (-2) | mean > 2) & deviation > 1.5)*1
```

You don't need the final `}else{}` clause since all the other conditions were set to zero by the first two assignments. I'm assuming the assignment to SAT$EXCEPTION_2 was a further typo that you have not yet fixed.

If you use `ifelse`, you need to understand that it is not possible to put in assignments and certainly not multiple assignments to different vectors.

Comment: @BondedDust...sorry for the mistake..edited the changes..it will be deviation